# adding custom options

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, migration

I'm migrating data from another platform to magento.

I'm looping over each product and inserting the data i've generated.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p['magento_id']);
if(!$product->getOptionsReadonly()) {
    $product->setProductOptions($pvars);
    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
    $product->save();
}
```

what seems to be happening is that its adding the data, but also data from the previous inserts also, so i have multiple custom options called "Door Colour".
the $pvar data is as it should be (see below).

$pvars contains:

```
Array
(
    [83] => Array
        (
            [title] => Door Colour
            [type] => drop_down
            [is_require] => 1
            [sort_order] => 0
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Grey
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 83-83-grey
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Dark Blue
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 83-84-dark-blue
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Red
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 83-85-red
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Maroon
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 83-86-maroon
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Pastel Blue
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 83-87-pastel-blue
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Yellow
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 83-88-yellow
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Green
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 83-89-green
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [435] => Array
        (
            [title] => 11 Door Lock Option
            [type] => drop_down
            [is_require] => 1
            [sort_order] => 0
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Cam Locks (Free)
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 435-90-cam-locks--free-
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Padlock Fitting (Free)
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 435-91-padlock-fitting--free-
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => 4 Digit Combination Locks
                            [price] => 253.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 435-92-4-digit-combination-locks
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => £1 Coin Return Locks
                            [price] => 302.50
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 435-93---1-coin-return-locks
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Electronic Combination Locks
                            [price] => 495.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 435-94-electronic-combination-locks
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [761] => Array
        (
            [title] => Size (mm)
            [type] => drop_down
            [is_require] => 1
            [sort_order] => 0
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => 1800h x 1500w x 450d (11ARCH)
                            [price] => 0.00
                            [price_type] => fixed
                            [sku] => 761-95-1800h-x-1500w-x-450d--11arch-
                            [sort_order] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

worked it out, for anyone interested:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p['magento_id']);
foreach($pvars as $optionData)
{
  $product->setHasOptions(1);
  $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
          ->setProductId($p['magento_id'])
          ->setStoreId(1)
          ->addData($optionData);
  $option->save();
  $product->addOption($option); 

  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
  $product->save();  
}
```

Comment: Actually it is a bug as the same happens with the internal API, glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Trev thanks for sharing your solution - feel free to accept your own answer as the answer to mark this question as solved